# How to Update a record in text file?

Tags: c#

here i my code its a function that updates value its not working ...

```
            public void UpdateInFile(string modified,int id)
            {
               string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("items.txt");
               for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
               {
                 if (lines[i][0] == id)
                 {
                    lines[i] = modified;
                 }
               }
               File.WriteAllLines("items.txt", lines);
            }
```

here modified is the modified string and data is stored in it as

id,Description,price,quantity

i want to replace data stored against particular id

Comment: what's the problem ?

Comment: "its not working" - what is your input, what is the file content, what exactly is happening?

Comment: `lines[i][0] == id` seems problematic to me. You compare the first character of id which is a `char` with an `int`. I don't think this is what you want.

Comment: So your input string is a four fields of data a comma delimited. And I suppose that the lines in your file have the same format right?

Comment: problem is file is not updating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the lines in your file have the same format of your input string then you need to apply a split to each line and check if the first element of the splitted line matches your input id

```
    public void UpdateInFile(string modified,int id)
    {
       string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("items.txt");
       for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
       {
          string[] parts = lines[i].Split(',');
          if (Convert.ToInt32(parts[0]) == id)
          {
             lines[i] = modified;
          }
       }
       File.WriteAllLines("items.txt", lines);
   }
```

Said that and not knowing what are your constraints on this task I really suggest you to look at some kind of database systems. There are some that are really simple to use and doesn't require complex installations. Of course you are required to learn how to use the classes in the NET Framework that interact with a database (Search for ADO.NET tutorials)

Comment: thank you so much it solved my problem although my problem was not well explained 
and thanks for suggestion will work on it too,i am new to c# therefore i started with file system

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to compare between a char to an int.

```
if (lines[i][0] == id) {}
```

Try using:

```
int output;
if (int.TryParse(lines[i][0], out output)) {}
```

Good luck

Comment: This will not work if `id` is represented with more than one digit.